# How do I set the width of a text box in CakePHP using the 'style' option?

Tags: php, cakephp

I m doing an app in CakePHP, JQuery and Mysql. In my homepage I am listing all my form names. When I click on a form name, it will show the form. Within that view, I have code that looks like this

```
<?php echo $form->input($r['Attribute']['label'], array(
                           'type'=>'text',
                           'style"=width:' => $r['Attribute']['size']
      ));
?>
```

to generate a textbox with the label that I got it from $r['Attribute']['label']
and to keep the width of it using that style. However, the width is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
<?php
    echo $form->input($r['Attribute']['label'], array('type'=>'text','style' => 'width:' . $r['Attribute']['size'] . 'px'));
?>
```

Two things: Your array key->value pairing was messed up, and you need to give units to the width. I assumed that want you wanted to give it was a width in pixels, but if you just want to set the size of the input field you can do this:

```
<?php
    echo $form->input($r['Attribute']['label'], array('type'=>'text', 'size' => $r['Attribute']['size']));
?>
```

Comment: Er, what does it do? I just tested the first one and it works fine.